# Recortar cadena en Java con el metodo substring()

Tags: java

La verdad he buscado pero no logro poder encontrar un metodo o alguna forma de poder recortar esta cadena de una forma sencilla:

45.79.102.89/resources/images/courses/J22F5TEI6Oiso-17024.jpe

Quiero guardar en una base de datos el nombre de la imagen o sea "J22F5TEI6Oiso-17024.jpe" pero no se como puedo recortar lo que sobra, lo que se me ocurre es hacer que encuentre el último "/" y de ahi guardar lo que sigue o recortar lo anterior pero no se como lograrlo en codigo, les agradeceria su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Has probado a usar `.split("/")`?

Comment: Hay muchas formas, pero la más sencilla es el método *split* de la clase *String*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias maneras de hacer esto, pero yo lo suelo hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
String cadena = "45.79.102.89/resources/images/courses/J22F5TEI6Oiso-17024.jpe";
        
System.out.println(cadena.substring(cadena.lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
```

Esto devuelve:

> J22F5TEI6Oiso-17024.jpe

Es decir, le indicas que quieres la subcadena a partir del último carácter que termine con "/" y le sumas 1 (recuerda que empezaría por 0).

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias bro exactamante lo que necesitaba :).